# LibreOffice/Excel: SUM an adjacent cell if the value in the conditional cell is equal to N (SUMIF(?))

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

**Disclaimer:** *I have no idea what I'm doing.*

In LibreOffice Calc (3.6.2.2), I'm trying to `SUM` all of the values in `G:x` (where range is G2:G529), where `B:x` is equal to a given number `N`.

The data set that I'm working with has been derived from a list of strings - the goal is to: find all strings of length `N` where N is hard-coded into the query string.

[image: Data (snippet)]

Pseudocode:

> If B:x is n: add G:x to SUM

Attempt (where N=1):

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B529, "1"), G2:G529)
```

### Any suggestions?

> PS: For the sake of semantics, assume that LibreOffice Calc ==
>   Microsoft Excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Excel you can use SUMIF function like this

`=SUMIF(B2:B529,"1",G2:G529)`

The same formula should work in Libre Office

Comment: To confirm: it does, indeed, work a treat in LibO Calc. Just what I needed, too.

Comment: This did indeed work for me too. I had to replace the commas with semicolons though, like this: `=SUMIF(B2:B529;"1";G2:G529)`